# Apertura de web en la misma pestaña html

Tags: html

Para una extensión de Chrome, querría que al hacer click en un texto, en la misma ventana, se abriera un enlace. Por lo que tengo entendido, se debería usar _self. No obstante, la única manera que he encontrado para que el enlace se abra ha sido usar target="_balnk", el cual lo abre en una pestaña aparte.

código:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="Ir a Youtube :)" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
```

Comment: No entiendo. ¿En qué parte de tu extensión estás poniendo el enlace? ¿Lo estás inyectando desde un content script? ¿o es en otra parte?

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta especificar el target a self cuando la `URL` es completa, es decir utiliza un prefijo válido (`http` | `https`)

```
<a href="https://google.com">ir a google</a>
```

Tu anterior código está bien, no debería haber ningún problema en cualquier navegador que cumpla con DOM Level1 Core de la W3C

Comment: Aclararía que DOM lvl1 son prácticamente todos.

Answer (score 2):

No hay necesidad de usar el atributo target si queres que el enalce se abra en la pestaña actual:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" title="Ir a Youtube :)">YouTube</a>
```

Solo habria necesidad de especificarlo si estuvieses usando la funcion open de javascript:

```
window.open("https://www.youtube.com","_self");
```

Comment: El problema es que si lo hago así, al hacer click no hace nada